# If $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)$ exists, prove $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow p} f(x) \ \forall p$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm trying to solve the problem 19 in Manfred Stoll's "Introduction to Real Analysis", Exercises 4.1

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y) \ \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. If $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)$ exists, prove (a) $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) = 0$ and (b) $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p} f(x)$ exists $\forall p \in \mathbb{R}$.

I solved (a) by 
$\begin{align}
f(2x) & = f(x)+f(x) \\
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(2x) & = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) + \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) \\
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) = \lim_{2x \rightarrow 0} f(2x) & = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) + \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) \\
\therefore \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) & = 0,
\end{align}$ 
but I have no idea to solve (b). Is there any hint for (b)?

Comment: Try $f(p+y)=f(p)+f(y)$ with $y\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Hint: $f(x)=f(x-p)-f(-p)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for any $h\in \mathbb{R}$

$f(p+h)=f(p)+f(h)$

$\displaystyle \lim_{h\to 0} f(p+h)=\lim_{h \to 0}f(p)+ \lim_{h \to 0}f(h)$

Now,
$\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0}f(h)=0$

So,we get
$\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0}f(p+h)=f(p)$
We are done.